# Nested For Loop to activate slideshow and turn off another

Tags: slideshow

I  have multiple slideshows but only want one running chosen by id. The rest turned off and hidden.
I have the first one loading onload.
I have a nested for loop running through and turning them on and off.
This is not working consistently.

Some of the code I found on the internet. the outer for loop runs before any id is even chosen.
I don't even know if the active slider is being stopped properly before the new one is activated.
My loops seem to work correctly with just alerts and no code for the slideshow.
Then when I introduce the slideshows it works sometimes but not consistently. 
Choosing id 1 or 2 seems to work but sometimes it will not loop through the nested  3 or 4.
Some kind of conflict or is it logic error?
Please help this desperate beginner. I volunteered to do this for our choir
I am sorry that I wasn't able to format the code properly for viewing.

ok, I added jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5s0q30s8/

with the loops using only alerts.

```
 <button id=1>Group Photos</button>
 <button id=2>Miscellaneous</button>
 <button id=3>Trips</button>
 <button id=4>Old Pictures</button>
<script>

    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (var i=0; i <= buttonsCount; i+=1){
        buttons[i].onclick=function(e){
        var id= this.id;
        alert(id + ' clicked');
        for (var i=1; i <= buttonsCount; i+=1){
             alert('nested for' + i);
             if (i != id) {
             var temp = ('.slider-wrapper ' + i)
             alert('Not id ' + temp);
             $('.slider-wrapper' + i).hide();
             /*  $('#slider' + i).hide(); */
             $('#slider' + i).data('nivoslider').stop(); 
              }
             else {
             alert('true '+ i);
             $('.slider-wrapper' + i).show();
             $('#slider' + i).nivoSlider({       effect: 'fade'       }  ); 
            } //end else

            } //end nested for
        };
    } //end for
  </script>

 <div class="slider-wrapper1 theme-default">
               <div id="slider1" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/Choir2014.jpg" alt="" title="2014" />
                   ........More images.                           
                 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="slider-wrapper2 theme-default">
               <div id="slider2" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/Choir2014.jpg" alt="" title="2014" />
                   ........More images.                           
                 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slider-wrapper3 theme-default">
               <div id="slider3" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/Choir2014.jpg" alt="" title="2014" />
                   ........More images.                           
                 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slider-wrapper4 theme-default">
               <div id="slider4" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/Choir2014.jpg" alt="" title="2014" />
                   ........More images.                           
                 </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider1').nivoSlider({       effect: 'fade'       });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Could you add fiddle plz?

Comment: N. Molderf,  thank you so much for replying.I am sorry, I don't know how to add fiddle. I would love to . I will look that up on the internet. thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5s0q30s8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say, your code is very messy in my eyes. I do see you made an effort at using jQuery, so I will assume you are able to use that.

Your goal as I understand it:

- There are 4 sliders
- There are 4 buttons
- You click one button, and the respective slideshow shows up.

```js
$('#slideButtons button').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#content .slide:visible').hide();
  $('#content #c' + id).show();
  // Any other logic can be put here, like starting or stopping sliders.
});
```

```css
/* Show the first slider, and hide everything else by applying display:none to it */
#content div:not(#c1) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideButtons">
  <button id="1">1</button>
  <button id="2">2</button>
  <button id="3">3</button>
  <button id="4">4</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="slide" id="c1">Number 1! Put Slideshow 1 here.</div>
  <div class="slide" id="c2">Number 2! Put Slideshow 2 here.</div>
  <div class="slide" id="c3">Number 3! Put Slideshow 3 here.</div>
  <div class="slide" id="c4">Number 4! Put Slideshow 4 here.</div>
</div>
```

From here you can build it out. I'm sure it will look a lot cleaner too then. Also, if you are going to debug with that many alerts, try using `console.log` instead of `alert`. It's a lot less intrusive and you can simply read through it.

Comment: Thank you so much Rizky for your time.

Comment: Thank you so much Rizky for your time. I appreciate your opinion on my sloppy code and for the code that your wrote for me to use. I know very little about the dom or jquery. I  am trying to learn this as fast as I can but I bit off more than I can chew.  I tried console.log and I see how it works now. Yes the alerts were really irritating as it went through the iterations.  I will copy this code and work on it later today. I am not sure if it is clear that I wish to have the ACTIVE slideshow turned off when another is chosen. If I am making any forum faux pas please let me know. geddeca

Comment: If you want only the active slideshow to hide/stop, I'll show you how that's done using the `:visible` selector, which selects objects that are currently visible in the DOM. I'll edit my code. It'll basically be `$('#content .slide:visible').hide();` to hide that single one.

Comment: Rizky . I feel foolish because I believe that I have copied your code and placed it correctly, but I am getting all 4 divs c1 to c4 visible at the same time. I wanted to show the code  here but don't know where to post it. this comment box is not the place. I put the css in a file and linked to it. I added <script></script> around the code. all in <html> <body>

Comment: @geddeca Make a new jsfiddle with what you want to paste in there.

Comment: Ok, I had somehow removed the div content. I added it back in and now the css is working (only one visible at once.) but the script is not running at all. I have it just inside body.  <script>
    $('#slideButtons button').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     alert(id)
    $('#content .slide:visible').hide();
    $('#content #c' + id).show();
    // Any other logic can be put here, like starting or stopping sliders.
    });
</script>

Comment: Me commenting back . I moved the script underneath the buttons. It then worked properly. I guess it matters where the script is placed. Now I will try to add the slideshows. thank you

Comment: Good to know you found the cause. Hope merging my and your code will bring in a positive result.

Comment: Your code is so elegant. I appreciate your time. I have learned a lot about using id AND class to identify without needing to loop through. My coding experience was a long time ago with Access vb. Just coding on events. I need to change how I think :) Regarding this problem, I am still struggling with stopping the slideshows, not just hiding them. I used this code ('#c1').data('nivoSlider').stop(); but it doesn't stop it. first visible one works great but clicking on other ones  the erratic results of the slide timing start to happen. I was loading all 4 of them on load event.probably bad idea

Comment: OK, Got them to stop by changing ('#c1').data('nivoSlider').stop();  to: ...('nivoslider') in lowercase. hmm.  I had to add another layer of wrapper as this slideshow has the navigation of the slides and theme all in another wrapper. I must say again, thank you. If there is any way to click a thank you to you, please let me know. I definitely couldn't have done this without you.

Comment: Don't laugh! I don't have a clue how to accept and upvote. THis was my first post and although I am looking around I see nothing that say's accept. I would love to accept and upvote you. let me know how.

Comment: There is a greyed out check mark next to my answer, right under the 0. Click the arrow upwards to upvote the answer, and click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer but when I clicked to upvote it said that I needed "15" I guess that means that I don't have the status to upvote yet. I do have one more little question on selecting an element. I want to use the "not" like you did. here is what I tried but it didn;t work.  $(not('c'+ id)).data('nivoslider').stop(); Hope that you can answer this :)

Comment: You forgot the hashtag in front of `c`, that actually has to be stated.